# Multiple select box value does not inserting in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, insert

I tried to upload multiple select box value in my database using codeigniter but unable to do so. Every time i insert the value it just inserting one value.

**view:**

```
<?php echo form_open('admin/Doctors_controller/add') ?>
    <select class="form-control" name="timings[]" multiple>
      <option value="1">Apple</option>
      <option value="2">Mango</option>
      <option value="3">Blackberry</option>
    </select>
<?php echo form_close() ?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function add(){
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('timings[]','timings','required');

   if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('no','Doctor Could not be added');
        redirect('dashboards/doctor');
      }
      else{
        $this->Doctors_model->add_doc();
        $this->session->set_flashdata('yes','Doctor has been added');
        redirect('dashboards/doctor');
      }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function add_doc(){
      $data = array(
         'timings' =>implode(",", $this->input->post('timings[]'))
      );
      return  $this->db->insert('doctors',$data);
 }
```

**UPDATE**
 *When i changed the database field type to varchar then it is submitting properly*

By using this code i only able to insert one select box value .

Comment: var_dump($this->input->post('timings')); ?

Comment: Instead of inserting to database I did try with   

  echo "<pre>";
     print_r($data);
     echo "</pre>";
    die()
But i get the values with comma but then i tried to submit to database it only inserting one value

Comment: `'timings' =>implode(",", $this->input->post('timings[]'))` i have one thing to say **Stop using comma separated values in SQL..**

Comment: @RaymondNijland so what's the process i should do ?

Comment: Codeigniter active record has a function `insert_batch`  check it out.

Comment: Listen taht is for different purpose.My purpose is to inser in doctor database with selected category

Comment: @D.Dimitrov The result of var_dump is 
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "4" }